# Find all matching points in multiple CSV list

Tags: python, csv

I have 4 CSVs with 5 columns and over 500 rows.
1st column is say Plane. second is Points. 3rd and 4th are x and y coordinates of Points. 5th is Values.
For each Plane, there can be multiple Points. In each CSV Plane is matched. For e.g. Plane = 3 in 1 CSV is also Plane = 3 in other CSVs. But the Points number is different in all CSVs.

I want to find all the closest points for a given Plane, for all planes.
[image: CSV1]

[image: CSV2]

Result:

[image: Results]

These Planes can also change later, so I created a function that takes Plane numbers and matches points.

```
def matchPoints(plane_1,plane_2,plane_3,plane_4):
  algo:
  return matchedPoints, matchedValues
```

but I compare each point in a plane with all points of same plane in all 4 CSVs one by one.
Which makes the code very slow. Is there any alternative to speed up this process.

Comment: You can use `Pandas`

Comment: @Corralien I am using Pandas to read CSVs. But how can it be used to match Euclidean distance from 4 different CSVs?